# Any Powered By The Apocalypse game with a light, family-friendly theme?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse

By all I've seem, PbtA sounds like a system that is not focused or workable for a family-friendly PoV, unlike Fate, that have some good family-friendly settings, like ***Do, Young Centurions*** and ***Strays***. The more "family-friendly" setting I saw was ***The Warren***, and they give too much space for brutality, including the pregnancy (not because the pregnancy *per se*, but because a rabbit mother can Panic while giving birth). There's any hacks for PbtA that could go into a more light-hearted, family-friendly setting, like the ones I've cited from Fate?

I'm saying this because I'm working into a Fate setting with a vibe like *Get Along Gang* and *Jakers! The Adventures of Piggley Winks*, and I'm thinking on working the same setting as a PbtA hack, and I want to see some ideas.

Comment: Although game recommendation questions are off topic on the mainsite side, we have a number of PbtA experts who hang out in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) who might be able to help in that more informal setting. There are also some [RPG discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) where recommendations are welcome, which you might try.

Comment: Thanks to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/is-there-a-generic-rulebook-for-powered-by-the-apocalypse) I stumbled upon [this hack](http://story-games.com/forums/discussion/17652/apocalypse-world-for-kids-the-bureau-an-aw-hack-with-different-die-types) that claims to be kid-friendly (haven't read it yet). According to the link: _it's basically Men in Black meets Ghostbusters_.